# Brushes and test generation hide in github copilot labs - Visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-actions, github-copilot

I accidentally hided Brushes and test generation sections on github copilot labs extension's window and i can't find how to fix it and revocer[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z10Ww.png)

No idea what to do to show the sections
[Github copilot labs window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z45d.png)

Comment: try clicking the three dots at the top right of the sidebar view and see if there are unchecked options for those subsections that you want to re-check.